# Access violation calling printf from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, printf, masm

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and compiling this assembly program in 64 bits.
It compiles and links without any warnings but when I call the c function `printf`, I get `Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000024`?

```
extern printf: PROC

includelib libcmt.lib
includelib libvcruntime.lib
includelib libucrt.lib
includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib

.data
msg db 'hello world', 0Ah, 00

.code
main proc
    sub rsp, 40
    lea rcx, msg
    call printf
    add rsp, 40
    ret
main endp

End
```

Comment: you use static crt code (*libcmt.lib*) but not initialize it. you need call [*_initterm*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/initterm-initterm-e?view=vs-2019) first

Comment: @RbMm Could you give a code example how that would look like?

Comment: are you really want use **static** crt with asm ?! may be better dynamic ? or you sure that you need crt at all ?

Comment: @RbMm I could use a dynamic, I am just trying to get hello world to work, I did not find any examples where they were using dynamic libs

Comment: in this case you need declare `extern __imp_printf:QWORD` and call `call __imp_printf` also you must `call __imp_ExitProcess` at the end, where `extern __imp_printf:QWORD`. also you need use `includelib msvcrt.lib` and also `kernel32.lib`

Comment: @RbMm I have done as you said, includelib msvcrt.lib
includelib kernel32.lib, but I am getting unresolved external symbol __imp_printf. 
What is the different between __imp_printf:QWORD and printf, and why do I need to call exitProcess?

Comment: because if you use **import** symbol from some dll - you need declare symbol as `extern __imp_<symbol_name>:QWORD` (or `DWORD` for x86) - because you call it via pointer variable. why do I need to call `ExitProcess` ? but this need for process exit

Comment: ok - in your case - *__imp_printf* inside *includelib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib* - use it. also it ask *legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib* include. i use another crt, where `__imp_printf` inside *msvcrt.lib*

Comment: you need code look like https://pastebin.com/7KWPefVT and use `ep` as program entry point, and *legacy_stdio_definitions.lib legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib ucrt.lib* libs

Comment: @RbMm thanks for all the help:) My code looks like this now, https://pastebin.com/vuG8Xd6g it compiles but still crashes on the same place

Comment: @RbMm linking ucrt.lib did it:) thanks, what is the different between ucrt.lib and libucrt?

Comment: libucrt is static lib - code will be append to your binary. ucrt.lib is import library (__imp_ symbols) - code is in windows dll will be, not in your exe (which is will be small in this case, but have external dependencies)

Comment: Samantha you are the best, I was struggling with this thing for a few hours, no sources, no other things, I needed to add the ucrt.lib to my project too, after that printf worked fine. Also thanks @RbMm.